# How often does engine oil need to be replaced if the car is barely used?

Tags: engine, toyota, oil, oil-change

I have a Toyota with a 2001 engine in it. I have a trip coming up, and last changed the oil about 3 months ago.

During these three months, I've driven the car no more than 200 miles.

Do I still need to replace the oil? Or will the car be fine? Does sitting under the sun and doing nothing still necessitate an oil change?

Comment: [Is it mandatory to change oil once a year?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/13247/is-it-mandatory-to-change-oil-once-a-year).  Your question is different though.

Comment: It will vary with oil type and location conditions.  Toyota generally states 6month with a synthetic.

Comment: We can expect any oil placed in the engine in the past 3 months to be synthetic, right?

Comment: Parts stores still stock full synthetic, part synthetic and good old dino oil.  Lube houses and small garages option full synthetic.  Dealers will normally go with specified oil.  You would need to check where it was done last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oil gets old just from sitting exposed to air (oxidation). 3 months old should still be good, but do take a look at the colour of it on your dipstick. If it's dark, get it replaced.